# compare and merge output of different files with conditions

Tags: shell, awk, sed, paste

I have three files as below:

File1.txt

```
Add,abc,5
Add,xyz,10
Del,test,14
```

File2.txt

```
abc,123,567
abc,123,568
xyz,234,879
xyz,234,880
test,435,227
test,435,228
```

File3.txt

```
23
28
30
40
50
36
```

Where final desired output should looks like:

```
abc,123,567,23
abc,123,568,28,Add,abc,5
xyz,234,879,30
xyz,234,880,40,Add,xyz,10
test,435,227,50
test,435,228,36,Del,test,14
```

final output should be merged on comparing (abc,xyz,test).
I tried merging above files using "paste -d" command.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow,  good things: that you showed us the you have used `paste` command and you have used code tags for samples. Could you please also let us know the logic of getting output too? As it is NOT clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ paste -d "" <(paste -d, File2.txt File3.txt) <(sed 's/^/\n,/' File1.txt )
abc,123,567,23
abc,123,568,28,Add,abc,5
xyz,234,879,30
xyz,234,880,40,Add,xyz,10
test,435,227,50
test,435,228,36,Del,test,14
```

#### How it works

The first step is that you need to combine File2.txt with File3.txt:

```
$ paste -d, File2.txt File3.txt
abc,123,567,23
abc,123,568,28
xyz,234,879,30
xyz,234,880,40
test,435,227,50
test,435,228,36
```

Secondly, we need to doublespace File1.txt like this:

```
$ sed 's/^/\n,/' File1.txt

,Add,abc,5

,Add,xyz,10

,Del,test,14
```

Lastly we need to combine both of the above together with another paste command:

```
$ paste -d "" <(paste -d, File2.txt File3.txt) <(sed 's/^/\n,/' File1.txt)
abc,123,567,23
abc,123,568,28,Add,abc,5
xyz,234,879,30
xyz,234,880,40,Add,xyz,10
test,435,227,50
test,435,228,36,Del,test,14
```

`paste` expects files for arguments.  We have commands.  The construct `<(...)` converts the output of commands like `paste -d, File2.txt File3.txt` into file-like objects that `paste` can use.  `<(...)` is called *process substitution*.

We could have done the same thing using temporary files:

```
$ paste -d, File2.txt File3.txt >tmp1; sed 's/^/\n,/' File1.txt >tmp2; paste -d "" tmp1 tmp2
abc,123,567,23
abc,123,568,28,Add,abc,5
xyz,234,879,30
xyz,234,880,40,Add,xyz,10
test,435,227,50
test,435,228,36,Del,test,14
```

Process substitution eliminates the need for temporary files.